# embedding of local representation into automorphic representation

Tags: automorphic-forms

Assume $v$ is a place of a number field $k$, finite or not. Let $\pi_v$ be an irreducible admissible generic representation of $GL_n(k_v)$. Is it always true that we can find some irreducible generic automorphic representation $\Pi$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{A}_k)$ with $v$-component exactly isomorphic to $\pi_v$?

A form of the famous generalized Ramanujan conjecture says that if $\Pi$ is cuspidal, then every component is tempered. So the above question is kind of converse to Ramanujan conjecture.

It is known that if $v$ is a finite place, and $\pi_v$ is supercuspidal, then $\Pi$ always exists, and in fact we can take $\Pi$ to be a cuspidal representation.

Many thanks for any answer or references related to this question.

Comment: What do you mean by generic, in this context? 

Comment: Here it means there exists some automorphic form $\phi$ in $\Pi$, such that the associated Whittaker function $W_{\phi}$ is not identically zero.

Comment: Aren't there uncountably many local representations, but only countably many automorphic representations?

Comment: @AD: Yes, if you restrict to cuspidal GL(n) aut. reps.

Comment: @David: What exactly do you mean by automorphic representation? I used to understand a representation which occurs discretely in $L^2(G({\mathbb Q})\backslash G({\mathbb A})$.
If you fix a level, ie a compact open at the finite places, you get countably many automorphic representations by spectral geometry (cuspidals plus residues of Eisenstein series). As there are essentially countably many levels, you're done.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think here automorphic representation means any irreducible subspace of $L^2(G(\mathbb{Q})\G(\mathbb{A}))$. Those occurs discretely are cuspidal representations.

Comment: @AD: Sorry, I was answering the question you asked in the comment directly above my post.  If you go beyond cuspidal you get continua of Eisenstein representations, which can be irreducible but are never closed as subspaces of $L^2$.

Comment: But also the residual spectrum in L^2(G(Q)Z(R)^+ \backslash G(A)) occurs discretely right? For example if you take $G = GL_2$, then $L^2_{disc} = L^2_{cusp} \oplus L^2_{res}$, where $L^2_{res}$ is the direct sum of all cts characters of $Q^\times R^\times_{>0} \backslash A^\times$.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43962/local-to-global-principle-for-reductive-groups/43969#43969

Comment: And this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74238/embedding-of-local-tempered-representation-into-cuspidal-automorphic-representati

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you're still interested in the question, but Arthur proves something like this in his upcoming book on representations of classical groups (http://www.claymath.org/cw/arthur/pdf/Book.pdf):

Lemma 6.2.2 says that for $G=SO(n)$ or $Sp(2n)$, a local field $F\neq\Bbb C$, and a square-integrable irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G(F)$, there is a global field $K$, a place $v$, and an automorphic representation $\Pi$ in the discrete spectrum that has $\pi$ as the $v$-component and is spherical at all other finite places. 
(He needs the lemma to use the trace formula over the constructed global field $K$.)

And I think I've seen something like this also for other groups somewhere else, at least for $GL(n)$ (with weaker conditions on the remaining places).

Comment: Do you have the new link of that book or notes? Becasue the old one does not work anymore. Thank you!